# Visual Basic - How to check how many times a number goes into another

Tags: vba, algorithm, visual-studio

I need to check how many sixes can fit into a number entered by the user to be able to use it in my program later on. So for example, two sixes can fit into 13. I was wondering if there's an algorithm I can use for this.

Comment: Isn't that simple division?

Comment: Please clarify if you use vba (i.e. in an Excel macro) or vb.net (you tagged visual-studio).

Comment: To explain what everyone is saying about division: in the mathematical formula `a / b = c`, c is the *number of times b goes into a*. So for example, `13 / 6 = 2.16666...`, so `6` goes into `13` `2.16666...` times. If you don't care about the fractional part, you can use "integer division" (the \ operator instead of the / operator) to get the result truncated to a whole integer. In this case, `13 \ 6 = 2`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do an integer division. See the MSDN page about [arithmetic operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx) or the MSDN page about the [\ Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx):

```
Dim k As Integer
k = 23 \ 5
' The preceding statement sets k to 4.
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need that, simply divide one by the other and change to integer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx says

```
 number1 \ number2
```

returns the value you desire for VB, I presume it carries over to VBA.

Otherwise, you can use

```
CInt(Fix(number1/number2))
```

(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh29swte(v=vs.90).aspx)